# Converting strings into a hexadecimal string

Tags: c#, hex

Follow the snippet given below.

```
public static string NewPassword()
    {
        Ticket objTick = new Ticket();
        string shortStaffID = objTick.GetStaffID().Substring(0, 2);
        string tickNum = Convert.ToString(objTick.GetTicketNumber());
        string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss").Substring(0, 3);

        string combinePass = shortStaffID + tickNum + timeStamp;
        string hexPassword = int.Parse(combinePass).ToString("A");

        return hexPassword;
        
    }
```

I am trying to create password generator that will create a temporary password based on a staff ID for example: JohnD. Alongside with a ticket number which of int value and a timestamp which is also of int value.
The only problem is that **the Staff ID are strings and cannot be converted into a integer**.

I was wondering if there was a way to be able to convert the string into a hexadecimal string and combine all these strings/integers together to create a whole password to be display.

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

A curious set of requirements and logic, but why not GetHashCode to turn any length of string into an integer, then hex that

```
public static string NewPassword()
{
    Ticket objTick = new Ticket();
    string shortStaffID = objTick.GetStaffID().Substring(0, 2);
    string tickNum = Convert.ToString(objTick.GetTicketNumber());
    string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm").Substring(0, 3);

    string combinePass = shortStaffID + tickNum + timeStamp;
    string hexPassword = combinePass.GetHashCode().ToString("X8");

    return hexPassword;
    
}
```

I don't recall encountering A as a format specifier. I've always used X for hex. You can tag on a number to pad the result out to a certain number of digits for example X8

ps; any number when + to a string will concatenate so your code could simplify to the below, though note that that version generates new passwords every minute rather than every 10 (if every 10 is a requirement, put the datetime substring back in)

```
public static string NewPassword()
{
    Ticket objTick = new Ticket();
    string combinePass = objTick.GetStaffID() + objTick.GetTicketNumber() + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm");

    string hexPassword = combinePass.GetHashCode().ToString("X8");

    return hexPassword;
    
}
```

Comment: I'm doing an assessment based on creating a ticket system and my lecturer provided these requirements as well as showing that using the int.parse was the only way but thank you I will give this a try.

Comment: Yeah I was also fairly unsure of the "A" format specifier as it didn't manage to gain any information about it when researching but the X format specifier is doing exactly what I want it to do now so thank you!

Comment: Well, feel free to GetHashCode all the individual strings and take bits of them, like `Math.Abs(StaffId.GetHashCode()).ToString("000").Remove(2)` which will mean "if GetHashCode returns 98765 this wil produce 98". The whole thing is a bit weird though. Normally we would prepare a password that is NOT predictable. There are massive obvious problems with making predictable passwords

Comment: `GetHashCode()` can well return *different* output for *same* value on different .Net versions. So if hash is stored (say, in RDMS), it will be a problem with clients which are written on different C# / .Net versions

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It will even produce different values on the same PC with the same .NET version - it is only guaranteed to create the same value within a sinlge process instance, see https://andrewlock.net/why-is-string-gethashcode-different-each-time-i-run-my-program-in-net-core/. But as I understood the question it will be used only for a password suggestion, not for a permanent password

Comment: There are so many things I don't like about the driving premise of the question, but they're not things I really deemed particularly relevant to the core of "how can I turn a varying string into a varying int so I can ToString X it" which is my understanding of the question. Quite why it's not just `random.NextInt(int.MaxValue).ToString("X8")` I don't know, but I presume "simple academic contrivance to demonstrate some other concept"